# Unable to display dates and values on Chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following data stored in array:

```
var labelItems= ["3/27/20", "3/28/20", "3/29/20", "3/30/20", "3/31/20", "4/1/20", "4/2/20", "4/3/20", "4/4/20", "4/5/20", "4/6/20", "4/7/20", "4/8/20", "4/9/20", "4/10/20"]

var dataSets= [27198, 30652, 33925, 37582, 42107, 46809, 52983, 58787, 64606, 69374, 74565, 81865, 88338, 95455, 102525]
```

I have initialzed my line chart as follows:

```
 var ctx = document.getElementById('lineChart').getContext('2d');
        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            // The type of chart we want to create
            type: 'line',

            // The data for our dataset
            data: {
                labels: labelItems,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Deaths',
                    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                    data: dataSets
                }]
            },

            // Configuration options go here
            options: {}
        });
```

My issue is that the dates, that is the labels are not displaying on the x-axis nor the datasets on the y-axis. Can someone please help with this?

Comment: Your variables are `labels`, `datasets` and you are passing `labelItems`, `dataSets`

Comment: I corrected it.. just a typo. it still does not work.

Comment: Code seems to work here https://jsfiddle.net/anuragsr/zLhjt5nf/, are you using the correct id selector?

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html) say, you have to add the parser and tooltipFormat properties to the axis (x or y) in order to display the value.

```
    var ctx = document.getElementById('lineChart').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        // The type of chart we want to create
        type: 'line',

        // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Deaths',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                data: dataSets
            }]
        },

        // Configuration options go here
        options: {
          scales: {
            xAxis: [
              display: true,
              type: 'time'
              time: {
                parser: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm',
                tooltipFormat: 'll HH:mm',
                unit: 'day',
                unitStepSize: 1,
                displayFormats: {
                  'day': 'MM/DD/YYYY'
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
    });
```